# Debugging in Eclipse for C program can't find command line argument file

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, gdb

So I'm using Eclipse to debug a program of mine, and I set everything up, and under the arguments tab in the Debug Configuration I have an .in file used in my program. Whenever I try and run "Debug" I get the following error

&"Cannot exec bin/bash -c exec /nfshome/calzy8/eclipse-workspace/Lab4/Debug/Lab4 'testPipelineDataHazards1.in'.\n"

&"Error: No such file or directory\n"

I'm using the gdb debugger and the program runs fine whenever I click Run but whenever I try "Debug" it doesn't work

Can anyone help me out with this? I've read this post as well and it didn't help 
[Eclipse Debug Error: No such file or directory\n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273489/eclipse-debug-error-no-such-file-or-directory-n)

Answer (score 0):

Found the error, I used export SHELL=/bin/sh in a separate directory and I fixed this by going to the home directory and executing the same command